# Data type of function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, express, types

What kind of data should I put after `:` for this function?

```
public saveHistory(log: String): "HERE!" {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> => {
    try {
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: It is `(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response | void>` i think

Comment: No, its a method of class

Answer (score 2):

```
(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response | void>
```

You've listed it in your `return` statement, though without the `async` (you're already returning a Promise) and the syntax for a function return switches from `:` to `=>`. However, in most cases (including this one) you can also omit the `:` and allow TypeScript to infer your return type from your `return` statement.

```
function saveHistory(log: String):
    (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<Response | void> {
  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> => {
    try {
      // ...
    } catch (e) {
      // ...
    }
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchAewBiBXAdgY2ASwPZqgF4p0BrNXAdzQG4AoOgM3SzwIGcBDANwgAls7YLgBOIABQAbXAHMAXFADKwEdjQyAlAvEiIARwUAlfSghCANFF3sjZsPnYRLaBMAVxEqTDnwaiAPigABRFcAFtBCAAeY3Z7NEcoAB8oblxsABNAgG86KCsIYBQRAk52EEwoHX1bPVMLApsoWPjHZ1d3Vy9WXwUQ8MiYuwdoFLTMwMIcvPyoFRAoXNnZgHoVqAA6LZn8gF8oDE5gDAALKog-JeWoNc3t5d2Z3fpdoA)